# VectorPlot3D broken in Mathematica 11.0.1?

Tags: plotting, bugs

Here is what I get when simply evaluating the example in the documentation:

[image]

This is on Win7 x64. I can see some vectors if I do something like

```
VectorPlot3D[{1, 1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> 2]
```

but the plot I get:

[image]

has all vectors parallel to the z-axis and thus makes no sense.

**Update:**

I played around with this some more, and found that wrapping the vectorfield argument in a `Hold` fixes the issue:
Following david's comment, instead of using `Hold`, we can just put curly braces around the vector field, which would almost make sense, but see below...

I wonder whether this issue and [the one with StreamPlot I posted about](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127732/streamplot-oddness-in-11-0-1)
are somehow related. In the `StreamPlot` case, an `Evaluate` now needs to be wrapped around the argument to make things work. Did they somehow mess up the attributes of graphics functions in 11.0.1?

**More issues:**

```
scalarField = x^2 - y^2 - z; 
vectorField = D[scalarField, {{x, y, z}}]

VectorPlot3D[{{2 x, -2 y, -1}}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
 VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 5, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 VectorScale -> {0.2, Scaled[0.4]}]
```

This looks the way it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Now we're using the variable `vectorField`:

```
VectorPlot3D[{vectorField}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
 VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 5, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 VectorScale -> {0.2, Scaled[0.4]}]
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

so we see flat, 2D arrows. Bug. As in the `StreamPlot` bug, it turns out that wrapping `vectorField` in an `Evaluate` fixes the problem. It really looks like the improper behavior of `VectorPlot3D` and `StreamPlot` are related. One has to wonder what else might be affected.

Comment: O.k., I'm jumping the gun and have added the `bugs` tag.

Comment: Can you verify the nonsensical plots I have posted?

Comment: I get the same outputs as you if these plots are evaluated in any ref pages. Evaluated in a notebook, they work fine.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how it is possible for these plots to come out differently depending on the notebook they are evaluated in.

Comment: Ah, restart of *Mathematica*, and it's not working anywhere now.

Comment: Sorry about that ;-) On the other hand, I'm relieved to see that it's not just my system. I agree, let's wait for more people to weigh in on this, but with your independent verification I'm now fairly confident it's a bug. A nasty one at that, makes VectorPlot3D unusable, and who knows what else. I have a feeling this is related to them "fixing" some stuff related to the 3D crashes they had on MacOS, with the side effect that now Windows 3D is broken. Great.

Comment: I can confirm the problem on my system (Win 10, x64). However, if I put curly braces around the argument, it works fine. For example, `VectorPlot3D[{{x, y, z}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Can reproduce result of @david.  In addition, `Reap[VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, z}]]]`, based on the first `EvaluationMonitor` example in documentation, produces an empty list.  However, `ListPointPlot3D[ Reap[VectorPlot3D[{{x, y, z}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, z}]]][[-1, 1]]]` works well.

Comment: Note that second usage in documentation, `VectorPlot3D[{Subscript[field, 1],Subscript[field, 2],\[Ellipsis]},{x,Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]},{y,Subscript[y, min],Subscript[y, max]},{z,Subscript[z, min],Subscript[z, max]}]`, shows multiple vector fields in a `List`.  Evidently, Mathematica now requires that even a single vector field be enclosed in a `List`, i.e., `{{x, y, z}}`.  This would be consistent with usage in some other functions.  However, documentation should be revised to show this.  In my view incorrect documentation is a bug.

Comment: I agree. There's the additional wrinkle that `VectorPlot3D` apparently will produce output if the vector field has at least one constant component, but the output is wrong. A warning/error message might be appropriate in cases like this.

Comment: Same issue for me (on Windows 10). Has this been reported to Wolfram?

Comment: @SimonWoods it has. There is a paclet fix for it. I have to ask what info I can disseminate in how to get the fix.

Comment: Same problem here for version 11.0.1.0. Not even the simple example VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] works. But adding an extra layer of { } is a workaround. Is this officially a bug? or is any reasoning for the change of behavior? Version 11.0.0.0 worked just fine.

Comment: Well. I asked Mathematica support team about this issue. They couldn't reproduced the issue, and I couldn't either (problem fixed by itself). So one explanation for this could be is that fresh installations of Mathematica 11.0.1 at least in mac os systems presents the issue. No time now to test this theory.