# StreamPlot oddness in 11.0.1

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 and fixed in 11.1.0**

---

I have a streamplot I want to look at like so:

```
StreamPlot[{x - y, y^2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> "Line"]
```

[image]

In 11.0.0 I used to be able to do

```
v = {x - y, y^2};
StreamPlot[v, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> "Line"]
```

and obtain the exact same plot. However, now, in 11.0.1 I get

[image]

Long story short, `StreamStyle` directives are ignored in the second case. I can get things to work again by doing

```
StreamPlot[Evaluate[v], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> "Line"]
```

instead, but that should not be necessary. Another bug. I have this sinking feeling that I should not have "upgraded" to 11.0.1.

Comment: I can confirm it works as expected in 10.4.1 but not in 11.0.1.  You should report it to WRI.

Comment: I have reported both this and the issues with `VectorPlot3D`, and Wolfram Support has confirmed the bugs. Hopefully fixed in the next bug fix release.

Comment: I can confirm that the bug has been fixed in 11.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in 11.1.0.

```
v = {x - y, y^2};
StreamPlot[v, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> "Line"]
```

[image]